# How do I alternate graphics in LaTeX beamer

Tags: beamer, overlays

I'm trying to alternate graphics on a slide:

```
\frame{
\frametitle{Verkette Liste Beispiel} 
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics<1>[scale=0.7]{pics/List-0.pdf}
    \includegraphics<2>[scale=0.7]{pics/List-1.pdf}
    \caption<1>{Hallo}
    \caption<2>{Welt}
\end{figure}
}
```

My problem is I don't get alternating captions. I get something like this: http://public.kungi.org/main-faulty.pdf

I tried the solution from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088761/how-to-change-an-image-on-a-slide-in-latex but it did not work for me.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `\caption` command is not "overlay specification aware".  Instead of

```
\caption<1>{Hallo}
\caption<2>{Welt}
```

do

```
\caption{\only<1>{Hallo}\only<2>{Welt}}
```

Comment: It works fine but the numbers in captions are the same. Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 13):

use it this way:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Verkette Liste Beispiel}{}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics<1>[scale=0.7]{pics/List-0.pdf}
    \includegraphics<2>[scale=0.7]{pics/List-1.pdf}
    \caption{\only<1>{Hallo}\only<2>{Welt}}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```